# Pattern for caching data in Asp.Net Core + EF Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an Asp.Net Core + EF Core REST service. I created a DbContext class for a DB I want to call a SP on. The method pretty much looks like:

```
public IQueryable<xxx> Getxxxs()
{
    return Set<xxx>().FromSql("pr_Getxxx");
}
```

This all works, but there isn't any point in calling the SP every single time since the data the SP returns rarely changes. I'd like to make the data stale, say every 24 hours.

Is there a preferred pattern for doing that in Core? I see they have the .AddCaching extension method, but that seems like it would get injected into the controller? So its the controllers job to cache? I assume its thread-safe so I don't need to do any locking or anything like that? Seems like a race condition, if one thread is checking if the item is loaded into the cache, the other may be inserting it, etc?

Comment: Can you **PLEASE** stop calling it EF7. This name isn't officially used for like 6 months. It's called EntityFramework Core and is versioned as 1.0 to make it clear it's not the next version of EF6. Please refer to this announcement here http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5IsDeadIntroducingASPNETCore10AndNETCore10.aspx

Comment: Is this service running permanently or only running when invoked and terminated after that? You somehow need to cache the result and the timestamp of the time when you last accessed the data from database.

However, the Database should/might do a lot of this caching-stuff by itself.

Comment: @ThomasRoskop, the service is always running. The way Core works, the controller and the context are new'ed up on each call. They have the MemoryCache which can expire after X time. It just seems open to a race condition.

Answer (score 16):

Well, you can apply the [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). It's nothing .NET Core specific, just a common pattern.

```cs
public class MyModel
{
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }
}

public interface IMyRepository
{
    IEnumerable<MyModel> GetModel();
}

public class MyRepository : IMyRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<MyModel> GetModel()
    {
        return Set<MyModel>().FromSql("pr_GetMyModel");
    }
}

public class CachedMyRepositoryDecorator : IMyRepository
{
    private readonly IMyRepository repository;
    private readonly IMemoryCache cache;
    private const string MyModelCacheKey = "myModelCacheKey";
    private MemoryCacheEntryOptions cacheOptions;

    // alternatively use IDistributedCache if you use redis and multiple services
    public CachedMyRepositoryDecorator(IMyRepository repository, IMemoryCache cache)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.cache = cache;

        // 1 day caching
        cacheOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
            .SetAbsoluteExpiration(relative: TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
    }

    public IEnumerable<MyModel> GetModel()
    {
        // Check cache
        var value = cache.Get<IEnumerable<MyModel>>("myModelCacheKey");
        if(value==null)
        {
            // Not found, get from DB
            value = repository.GetModel();

            // write it to the cache
            cache.Set("myModelCacheKey", value, cacheOptions);
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

Since the ASP.NET Core DI doesn't support interceptors or decorators, your DI registration will become a bit more verbose. Alternatively use a 3rd party IoC container which supports decorator registrations.

```cs
services.AddScoped<MyRepository>();
services.AddScoped<IMyRepository, CachedMyRepositoryDecorator>(
    provider => new CachedMyRepositoryDecorator(
        provider.GetService<MyRepository>(),
        provider.GetService<IMemoryCache>()
    ));
```

This has the advantage that you have a clear separation of concerns and can easily disable the caching by changing the DI configuration to

```cs
services.AddScoped<IMyRepository,MyRepository>();
```

Comment: I recently created a sample demonstrating this approach here: https://github.com/ardalis/cachedrepository/

Comment: Shouldn't your CachedMyRepositoryDecorator.GetModel method actually call the MyRepository.GetModel method, rather than going to the DB directly? Seems to me, the way you've got it, you're not decorating MyRepository, you're just replacing it...iow if you don't call MyRepository.GetModel, why bother injecting MyRepository into the CachedMyRepositoryDecorator at all?

Comment: @JTech: You're right, copy & paste error. I think first I wanted had an example without decorator and later changed to it

Comment: There is an example on https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/tree/main/samples/core/Miscellaneous/CommandInterception

Answer (score 6):

you can use this third party package: https://github.com/VahidN/EFSecondLevelCache.Core

with AspNetCore MW & EfCore Extension (Cacheable) like this:

```
var posts = context.Posts
                   .Where(x => x.Id > 0)
                   .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
                   .Cacheable()
                   .ProjectTo<PostDto>(configuration: _mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
                   .ToList();
```

ProjectTo<>() is AutoMapper Extension.

Answer (score 3):

There is a sceond level caching extension that could do what you want. Its called [EntityFrameworkCore.Cacheable](https://github.com/SteffenMangold/EntityFrameworkCore.Cacheable) (yes its created by me, because I had a similar problem).

Here a sample base on the extension usage:

```
var cacheableQuery = cacheableContext.Books
    .FromSql("pr_Getxxx")
    .Cacheable(TimeSpan.FromHours(24));
```

The `Cacheable(...` method call store the first result into memory cache and return the cached result for 24h if the same linq expression is called again.

Comment: Generally, links to a tool or library [should be accompanied by install/usage notes, a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, or some sample code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605/584192), or if possible all of the above.

Comment: Does not work with EF Core >= 3.0.0 https://github.com/SteffenMangold/EntityFrameworkCore.Cacheable/issues/19

Answer (score 1):

You can use ASP.Net Core Memory Cache to cache the data. Then you can set the sliding/absolute expiration as per your need.
Refer to the documenttation of MemoryCahe
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-5.0